# Pascal Syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: syntax, compiler-errors, pascal

I am trying to figure out the issue with this piece of Pascal code

```
function Factorial(n: integer): integer;
begin
  if n = 0 then
    Result := 1
  else if n > 0 then
    Result := Factorial(n - 1) * n; 
end;
```

When I run the code I get the error
**-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `n:'**

Anyone can tell why that is? I am using the fpc (free pascal compiler) is this code meant for a different Pascal compiler?

Comment: That's not a Pascal error. It's an operating system error.

Comment: How did you try to compile this code? Did you try to run it like a bash script?

Answer (score 2):

That code compiles fine in fpc.

From the error message you quote, as @KenWhite says, it sounds like you are using the wrong tool to try to compile it - `bash` is an operating system shell for Linux and it is a `bash` error message.  `bash` is not for comiling Pascal code.

I suggest you download and use Lazarus, which is the freeware IDE for fpc and runs on Linux and Windows. Once you have Lazarus installed on your system, create a new project (a "simple project" from Lazarus's list of new project types.  Then copy/paste the code above the `begin ...end` of the project source, then save and compile it and you will see that Lazarus reports successfully compiling the project.

Btw, there is an omission from the code - it only covers cases where n is greater or equal to zero, so the function has an undefined result for n less that zero.

Comment: Lazarus should also be available for the Mac, BTW.